# Best way to share WiFi between two apartments

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to share the WiFi from one apartment unit to another. The setup is as follows:

[image]

Assume that there is no way to connect ethernet between the two apartments (would have been my strong preference). This current setup allows the downstairs unit to receive WiFi "OK", but it is often extremely slow and unreliable.

What is the best way to get a strong signal from the upstairs Router/WiFi transmitter? My research has suggested many options like mesh WiFi etc., but I don't want to spend money on trial and error devices - I already spent a couple of hundred on the best WiFi repeater I could and it hasn't done the job. I feel like this is a pretty common problem that many people around the world would have solved. Has anyone had success getting strong/reliable signals, and what did you do?

I can post more information about devices, distances etc. if it's relevant, but for now just assume standard telco-issued router, a decent WiFi repeater, and standard distances between units in an all brick/concrete/steel 4-storey building.

Comment: If a WiFi repeater didn’t work out then your only solution is for a hardline.

Comment: minimize the amount of "stuff" in the way ... if the path between two wifi devices is perpendicular to the concrete slab, there's less "stuff" in the way than if they are not - you may be surprised how much difference there is between 45 degrees and directly perpendicular - as for "standard distances" - which standard?

Comment: This is not possible to "answer" without a visit to the site. A suggestion: On your phone download e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer and investigate where you have the strongest possible signal, and which channel to select that has the least users (neighbors); then consider new placement of devices - and channel choice - based on your findings.

Comment: & work at 2.4GHz rather than 5, as it has better penetration.

Comment: Various things come to mind like high gain directional antennas on both ends and gluing one side to the ceiling. No idea whether this will result in a noticeable improvement, I have no experience with that.

Comment: Consider weatherproof transmitter and receiver on the balconies.  Make sure WPA2 or better security has a secure password.

Comment: @Hannu Thanks, yes I did perform a WiFi analysis which is why I placed the downstairs repeater there. It needs to plug directly into a power point, and out of all the power points in the unit that location received the strongest signal from upstairs.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, yes I operate at 2.4GHz not at 5 for that very reason.

Comment: @John Yes, this is why I included the balconies in the diagram - I was also thinking something like that, trying to get the signal to "curve" around the outside somehow since where I've labelled "building wall" there are actually floor to ceiling glass doors.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know which "standard" (I'm not in construction) but from my extensive travels most apartments around the world (studio, 1 bed, 2 bed) seem to converge around the same sizes. The slab to slab height seems to be 3m, floor area maybe 60sqm, which would make the apartments about 8x8m (given room sizes appear to be about 4x4m). I can't tell you much more than that.